# How to open excel always from top?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to set Excel behavior to opens always on top of the worksheet?
A lot of us are working on a long sheet and it would help if it opens on top and not where the last one saved it.

I do not need to lock the first row.

Alternatively, that it automatically scrolls all the way up
Thank you!

Comment: <CTRL><Arrow up> ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know (from using Excel for a long time) is for every user to press Ctrl - Home before saving.

You could probably write a macro to Ctrl - Home and Save, but then the user needs to remember to run the Macro.

Easier to develop the normal Excel habit to Ctrl - Home and then Save and Close.

Newcomers would have to be trained as well.

As noted, I have been doing this for a very long time.

Comment: You could map the macro to CTRL+S so it runs when you save from the keyboard. "Go home, save, go back where you were, mark as saved." Note: I am also not recommending this but it *is* possible.